# Powershell SSH / run on multiple machine simultaneously

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have this script ; Now I the script and it goes through each machine one by one. How can I make to run script simultaneously for all ips is in 'ip.txt' Thank you.

```
$Computers = $Computers = Get-Content -Path .\ip.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

foreach($Computer in $Computers){
Write-Host $Computer

    $User = "-"
    $Password = "-"
    $Command = 'hostname'

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command | Select -Expand Output | Add-Content -Path result.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Invoke-SSHCommand is from the PoshSSH module.  If so, the help documentation for that does not have a "-AsJob" parameter or anything that would cause it to run in the background.

Therefore you need to use PowerShell jobs in your script to invoke multiple commands at once.  This is a standard PowerShell jobs kind of question and as such it may be kind of redundant to answer it here.

```
$scriptBlock = {
    # You must pass any parameters that you want to use in your script block
    param(
        [String]$Computer,
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credentials,
        [String]$Command
    )
    $SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -AcceptKey:$true

    if ($SessionID)
    {
        # Any output that the Invoke-SSHCommand outputs will be allowed
        # to escape to the pipeline here because we don't assign the output
        # to a variable.  When you call Receive-Job, you will then get all of
        # the output that escaped to the pipeline (i.e. you will get the return
        # value of this command)
        Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command $Command
    }
    else
    {
        # Or provide your own error handling
        return "Could not create Session"
    }
}

# I'm confused what this does and if you need to call it each loop, or just once
Get-SSHTrustedHost | Remove-SSHTrustedHost

$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\ip.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

$hashTableOfJobs= @{}
foreach($Computer in $Computers) 
{
    Write-Host $Computer

    $User = "-" #ToDo, add username
    $Password = "-" #ToDo, add password
    $Command = 'hostname'

    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

    # This next line would have a problem if you had duplicates in your list 
    # of computers (because the HashTable needs keys to be unique)

    # Also note that the "Argument List" needs to provide the exact
    # arguments defined in your Script Block in the same order.
    $hashTableOfJobs["$computer"] = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($Computer, $Credentials, $Command)

    # Name is just a string for you to identify the job; I find it helpful later
    $hashTableOfJobs["$computer"].Name = "$Computer"
}

# At this point, $hashTableOfJobs contains a bunch of jobs that have been 
# run (or are still running).  We need to let all the jobs finish before
# we continue.

# A more sophisticated approach could loop through $listOfJobs and check
# the "State" of the job, and then write status and decide to wait longer
# To do that, check if ($_.State -like "*Running*")

# Option 1 for waiting for jobs
# Wait with a timeout of 10 seconds
$finishedJobs = $hashTableOfJobs.Values | Wait-Job -Timeout 10

# Option 2 for waiting for jobs
#     Left as a coding exercise for you =)

if ($finishedJobs.Count -ne $hashTableOfJobs.Count)
{
    # ToDo, some of your jobs didn't finish. Add error handling.
    Write-Warning "$($finishedJobs.Count) out of $($hashTableOfJobs.Count) jobs finished."
    # If your script is running on a lot of hosts and you don't plan to
    # close and restart the PowerShell window, then it is important to
    # clean up your job objects using the Stop-Job and Remove-Job cmdlets
}

# For below, you have to choose between Option 1 and Option 2.
# If you call "Receive-Job" twice, then you will only get output
# the first time you call it.

# Option 1 for receiving jobs: Look at only the finished jobs
foreach ($job in $finishedJobs)
{
    Write-Host "Receiving output for the $($job.Name) job"
    $thisJobOutput = Receive-Job -Job $job
    Write-Host "$thisJobOutput"
    Write-Host ""
}

# Option 2 for receiving jobs: Look at all jobs
foreach ($computer in $hashTableOfJobs.Keys)
{
    $job = $hashTableOfJobs[$computer]
    Write-Host "Receiving output for the $computer ($($job.Name)) job (state = $($job.State))"
    if ($job.State -like "*Running*")
    {
        Write-Warning "Oops, $($job.Name) on computer $computer didn't finish"
    }
    else
    {
        $thisJobOutput = Receive-Job -Job $job
        # Note, if you've already called Receive-Job, then you won't
        # get any more output, and this will be blank.  (We called 
        # "Receive-Job" above.  Delete that call and this will work)
        Write-Host "$thisJobOutput"
        Write-Host ""
    }
}

# Clean up job objects to prevent memory leak
$hashTableOfJobs.Values | Remove-Job
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put the code inside your `foreach` loop into a [scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2). You may need to make some subtle tweaks.

You can then pass this code block to the `-ScriptBlock` parameter of [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2), along with the array of `$Computers` to the `-ComputerName` parameter. This will allow you to run the scriptblock in parallel against multiple computers at the same time. If you need to throttle how many at once, you can use the `-ThrottleLimit` parameter.

Example 13 on the `Invoke-Command` documentation also shows an alternative method of running a 'script' on multiple computers at the same time, if you wanted to avoid using a script block.